# is there a way to change the criteria on a SQL statement using a input type text from html

Tags: php, html, sql, database

i am creating a receipt using php, html and mySQL but i need to be able to change the orderid that is specified in the sql statement:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE orderid =15'; 
$resultCustomer = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
<input type="text" name="name" value=<?php echo "{$orderid}" ?>>
<input type="submit" name="submit" align="right">
```

i need to be able to type a number in text box and when pressed submit the orderid from the above sql statement changes from 15 to the number typed in.

at the moment it is displaying what ever i add the the sql statement manually

help please :)

Comment: Your question actually spans several concepts: using prepared statements, using the super globals  $_POST $_GET or $_REQUEST, and possibly using the post-redirect-get pattern.  I will come back with an answer when I get to a computer later today, as this question will make a great reference for other posts

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate dynamic sql you should use the value posted by your form but do so in a safe manner rather than directly embedding a variable in the sql. To that end I put together a small example that might help ~ essentially the POSTed form variable `name` is used as the `orderid` in the sql but is used in a `prepared statement` ~ read the comments throughout for further explanation.

```
<?php

    $errors=[];
    $orderid=false;

    #require '/path/to/some/db-connection.php';


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        /* 
            You wish to POST a single field named "name" but use that as the "$orderid"
            so rather than attempt to embed directly in the SQL statement ( where you currently hardcode and ID )
            which would leave your code vulnerable to SQL injection, use a placeholder which can be bound to as
            we create a "Prepared statement"

            The filters *should* mean that we get rid of potentially bad characters from the POST data
            and are left with either an Integer or False.
        */
        $orderid=filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );

        if( $orderid ){

            /* only proceed if there is a valid db connection */
            if( isset( $conn ) && is_object( $conn ) ){

                /* generate the base sql statement with a "placeholder" to recieve variable */
                $sql = 'select * from `cust` 
                            natural join `orderpay` 
                            natural join `item` 
                            natural join `tran` 
                        where `orderid` =?';

                /*
                    create a `prepared statement` object.
                    Both `mysqli` and `PDO` support prepared statements
                    and help mitigate the threats posed by SQL injection.
                */
                $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
                if( $stmt ){
                    /* 
                        Next bind the placeholder to a variable. 
                        Here the `i` refers to an `Integer` though other types can be used, such as

                        s = string
                        d = double
                        b = blob
                    */
                    $stmt->bind_param( 'i', $orderid );

                    /* execute the statement - binding it's return value to a variable for later use */
                    $res=$stmt->execute();

                    if( $res ){
                        /* As the statement was executed successfully you can process the recordset */
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $rs=$stmt->get_result();
                        $stmt->close();

                        /* do something with recordset... */
                        while( $row=$rs->fetch_object() ){
                            echo $rs->FIELDNAME; # substitute for valid field/column name - or process recordset some other way.
                        }

                    } else {
                        $errors[]='No results';
                    }
                } else {
                    $errors[]='Unable to create prepared statement';
                }
            }else{
                $errors[]='No db connection';
            }
        } else {
            $errors[]='No OrderID';
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>POST OrderID - db select</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>

            <?php
                /* if there were errors, let user know perhaps */
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $errors ) ){
                    printf('<pre>%s</pre>', implode( PHP_EOL, $errors ) );
                }
            ?>

            <input type='number' name='name' value='<?php echo $orderid;?>' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good solid answer :) but one thing I’d point out: using post is for changing data; get is for reading data. As written the user will be prompted to resubmit if they hit the back button (it’s a pet peeve for me).

Comment: i dont understand how this would change the orderid in the &sql statement after entering a number in the box and pressing submit

Comment: The number you enter in the input field ( named `name` ) is used as the `orderid` - correct? Or that is what you would like to do - correct?? If yes, the form submits that value. The PHP code processes `$_POST['name']` and uses that as the `$orderid` variable. That variable is substituted into the `prepared statement` and the sql query runs using that variable as input - in a safe way

Comment: when ever i connect my database it causes an error on these lines: $stmt->store_results();
                        $rs=$stmt->get_result();
                        $stmt->close();                           this is how i am connecting$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','abcd','test1234','test');                              i get the error "call to undefined method..."